# Issue with passing object to child react componenet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am using react, currently I need to display a html list, in `LocationFinderList` I am initializing `Location` elements but `Location` does not get the object and instead I get only numeric property as shown in the pictures.

How to fix my script so `Location show the name for an object passe from`LocationFinderList`?

Could be an issue with spread operator?

Notes: location in `locations` object in `LocationFinderList` are defined as properties of an object not as items in an array.

---

```
{
                2643743: {
                    name: "London",
                    country: "GB"
                },
                4119617: {
                    name: "London",
                    country: "US"
                }
}
```

---

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Location from './Location';

const LocationFinderList = ({ locations, onLocationClick }) => (
    <ul>
        {Object.keys(locations).map((location, index) =>
            <Location
                key={index}
                {...location}
                onClick={() => onLocationClick(location.id)}
            />
        )}
    </ul>
);

export default LocationFinderList;
```

---

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const Location = ({ onClick, location }) => (
    <li
        onClick={onClick}
    >
        {location}
    </li>
)

export default Location;
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `Object.keys` to map over you will get the keys as a result and hence if you want to pass the object you need to pass it like `locations[location]`

Change you code to

```
const LocationFinderList = ({ locations, onLocationClick }) => (
    <ul>
        {Object.keys(locations).map((location, index) =>
            <Location
                key={index}
                {...locations[location]}
                onClick={() => onLocationClick(location)}
            />
        )}
    </ul>
);
```

And

```
const Location = ({ onClick, name, country}) => (
    <li
        onClick={onClick}
    >
        {name}
    </li>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
    {...locations}

to 
    {...locations[location]}